# PHP 5.4 console with WAMP?

Tags: php, windows-7

1. How can I access the new PHP console and PHP web server with WAMP?

Comment: I'm guessing maybe I shouldn't be using WAMP if I want to use advanced/new features?

Comment: You can be using WAMP for completely modern features. You just need to install them on your server as I indicated how to do below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from page [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

click `Download php Addons` (select your custom version And Download)

Comment: On the WAMP website PHP 5.4.x is not yet available, as it was just released. At a later date, or for a previous version, this is of course the obvious solution! :)

Answer (score 2):

**[This should do the trick.](http://www.dotkernel.com/php-development/how-to-upgrade-wamp-to-php-5-3-4/)**

Linked above is a quick tutorial on upgrading your WAMP server to newer PHP. Even if the version of PHP in this tutorial is outdated, the process remains the same for whatever version you desire.

Cheers.